# flalign doesn't work in for me

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

I want to left justify my equations using flalign. However,it works in some places and doesn't in others. Below is a sample of my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%%%%%No Hypernation%%%%%
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Homework 3}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\begin{enumerate}


\item Write an ODE file to return the following derivatives
\begin{flalign*}
\pd{n}{t} &= \left( 1-n \right) \alpha_n\left( V\right)-n\beta_n\left(V\right)\\
\pd{m}{t} &= \left( 1-m \right) \alpha_m\left( V\right)-m\beta_m\left(V\right)\\
\pd{h}{t} &= \left( 1-h \right) \alpha_h\left( V\right)-h\beta_h\left(V\right)\\
\pd{V}{t} &=-\dfrac{1}{C}\left(G_kn^4\left(V-E_k\right)+G_{Na}m^3h\left(V-E_{Na}\right)+G_L\left(V-E_L\right)\right)
\end{flalign*}
and the following constants ( $C$ is membrane capacitance, $G$ are the conductances and
$E$ are the reversal potentials of the potassium ( $K$ ), sodium ( $Na$ ), and leak ( $L$ )
channels):
\begin{flalign*}
\alpha\\
C &=1\\
G_K  &= 36\\
G_{Na} &= 120\\
G_L &= 0.3\\
E_K  &= -72\\
E_{Na} &= 55\\
E_L &= -49.4
\end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Side note: Upright `d` symbols for differentials look better

Comment: Don't use `flalign`. Use `align` instead and the `fleqn` option for `amsmath`, as in `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.

Comment: the `fl` in the `fleqn` option stands for flush left, the `fl` in `flalign` stands for **f**ull **l**ength, not flush left. Don't blame me, I didn't think of the names:-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I disagree: it looks worse. It's basically a stylistic decision, when the document is about pure mathematics. In some technical fields you're required to use an upright “d”, but that's a different story.

Comment: @egreg: I disagree to your opinion. In Physics/Science upright `d` are preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alignment should be used with, well `align` or `align*` and left align with `fleqn` option of the `amsmath` package.

In my point of view the constant block should use two (or even three constants) per row, not one large column.

And I've changed the `differentials` `d` to use upright characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%%%%%No Hypernation%%%%%
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\mathup}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}%

\title{Homework 3}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\mathup{d} #1}{\mathup{d} #2}}
\begin{enumerate}


\item Write an ODE file to return the following derivatives
\begin{align*}
\pd{n}{t} &= \left( 1-n \right) \alpha_n\left( V\right)-n\beta_n\left(V\right)\\
\pd{m}{t} &= \left( 1-m \right) \alpha_m\left( V\right)-m\beta_m\left(V\right)\\
\pd{h}{t} &= \left( 1-h \right) \alpha_h\left( V\right)-h\beta_h\left(V\right)\\
\pd{V}{t} &=-\dfrac{1}{C}\left(G_kn^4\left(V-E_k\right)+G_{Na}m^3h\left(V-E_{Na}\right)+G_L\left(V-E_L\right)\right)
\end{align*}
and the following constants ( $C$ is membrane capacitance, $G$ are the conductances and
$E$ are the reversal potentials of the potassium ( $K$ ), sodium ( $Na$ ), and leak ( $L$ )
channels):

\begin{align*}
\alpha & & C           &=1\\
G_K  &= 36 & G_{Na}  &= 120\\
G_L &= 0.3 & E_K  &= -72\\
E_{Na} &= 55 & E_L &= -49.4 
\end{align*}

% All in a column %

\begin{align*}
\alpha\\
C &=1\\
G_K  &= 36\\
G_{Na} &= 120\\
G_L &= 0.3\\
E_K  &= -72\\
E_{Na} &= 55\\
E_L &= -49.4
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are so many wrong `\left`–`\right` pairs! `:-(`

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but it's not my job to correct anything, in my point of view

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
```